# Truffle in production it´s recommended

Tags: truffle

It´s recommended to use the truffle framework for production?? Or just to develop purpose??

I mean can I connect my truffle to my private blockchain and execute the compile/migrate commands without hesitation. Or it´s better to do this without truffle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but...

I've found Truffle's deployment-syntax to be very cumbersome, and ended up implementing my own deployment code (though I still run it via `truffle deploy` or `truffle migrate`).

Here is an example:

```
let ARG1 = process.argv[4];
let ARG2 = process.argv[5];
let ARG3 = process.argv[6];

async function deploy(contractName, contractArgs = []) {
    let handle = await artifacts.require(contractName).new(...contractArgs);
    console.log(`${contractName} contract deployed at address ${handle.address}`);
    return handle;
}

async function execute() {
    let contract1 = await deploy("Contract1", [ARG1, ARG2]);
    let contract2 = await deploy("Contract2");
    let contract3 = await deploy("Contract3", [ARG3, contract1.address, contract2.address]);
}

async function measure() {
    let gasPrice   = web3.eth.gasPrice;
    let bgnBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
    await execute();
    let endBalance = web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
    console.log(`Total cost: ${bgnBalance.minus(endBalance).div(gasPrice)} gas units`);
}

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    if (network == "production")
        deployer.then(async function() {await measure();});
};
```

Then calling:

```
truffle deploy --network=production 0x123 0x456 0x789
```

Of course, you'll need to add the `production` network in your `truffle-config.js` file, for example:

```
networks: {
    development: {
        host:       "127.0.0.1",
        port:       8545,
        network_id: "*",
        gasPrice:   0x1,
        gas:        0x1fffffffffffff
    },
    production: {
        host:       ...,
        port:       ...,
        network_id: ...,
        gasPrice:   100000000000,
        gas:        6721975
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can´t undestand the purpose of your code. 0x123 0x456 0x789 values what mean? The rest I undestand and it result me very usefull. Concrectly truffle-config.js production part.

Comment: @Eduardo: They go into `ARG1`, `ARG2` and `ARG3`. This is useful if you need to pass inputs arguments to constructors.

Comment: Yes, but I mean what is the purpose with this js file?? 0x123 0x456 0x789 what represent?

Comment: @Eduardo: It's an example of how you pass arguments when you call `truffle deploy`!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think at this stage of Ethereum (4 years old) and Truffle (3 years old), we can definitely recommend the Truffle suite to deploy contracts safely anywhere. It's a trusted software recognized by the entire Ethereum community.

However, it doesn't make your private key safe or anything like that. You are responsible for the security of your private keys used to deploy those contracts.

Comment: Understand thx for the info ;D

Comment: Look, truffle may be the best thing available for the job, but it is far from reliable for anything over medium complexity. The Ethereum ecosystem has a long way to go before it is usable for normies. Truffle's error messages, if you are lucky enough to get one, are frequently wrong, sending you on a wild goose chase. I have used truffle for years and have still not desensitized to its nonsense.